# Enabling html5 mode with AngularJS and a external NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, heroku

So I've read almost every SO answer/question to this topic, but still I have many questions in my head.

First, the problem:

I have an AngularJS app with html5 enabled, so I can get rid of the '#' sign.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true });
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

This is the important part in my **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="application" ng-controller="ApplicationController as app">
  <head>
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">

    <title>LivingRoomArt</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/index.html" />
```

I am communicating with a **NodeJS server which is using express:**

```
router.route('/events')
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated, eventController.postEvent)
  .get(eventController.getEvents);

// Register all our routes with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// Start the server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

So, the usual problem:

**After reloading, I am getting an 404 from the server. I get the concept of this here, the suggested solution everywhere:**

```
  // This route deals enables HTML5Mode by forwarding missing files to the index.html
  app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
  });
});
```

> The thing is, I don't have an index.html file on my server, neither do
>   I want to duplicate it on my server.

So how do I tell Node to handle requests properly without storing html-files on my server?

**I am hosting the Node app on Heroku, if this helps.**

Comment: So you have a client server and an API server, right ? 
The 404 error is handle on the client server ?

Comment: Well, right now nowhere :) But I could handle it on the client, yes. And I have an API server and a static server for my client (html, js etc.)

Comment: And then what? I need to access sub-views and make AJAX calls there.

Comment: How come you don't have index? How would ng-app load? You definitely have a starting point, why not use it? `res.sendFile('file'); // res.render('file');`

Comment: Well, read the question. My Front End (Angular) is on a seperate static server, the NodeJS app runs on a different server (hosted at heroku). I don't serve the static files. My starting point is a index.html file, which just makes Ajax calls to a REST Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you don't serve static files, you're saying that the node.js API isn't right?

I guess you end up with two distinct urls, let's call them `http://api.com` and `http://client.com`.

I don't understand why your API should handle the 404. Do you load `http://api.com` in your browser and expecting your `index.html`? If it's really your use-case, I would advice a simple routing to declare in your API like:

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.redirect('http://client.com');
});
```

Which will redirect all requests not catched by your previous routes declaration to your client website.

---

Then, there is two options:

If the server that serves your static files is another Node.Js server using express, you could perfectly do the `sendfile`, since you now have access to the `index.html`

If you're using Nginx, (which I strongly recommend if you don't) for the statics, you could do a configuration like this to redirect all failed requests (missing files / routes) to the `index.html`

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /app/www;
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow. Just read this now but I can answer one question: The https://api.com is not returning the index.html, it returns just blank. It's a pure REST api. Maybe this will change the answer a bit? For nginx. No, I don't. Can you recommend a service to do this?

Comment: Hum yeah it's perfectly normal that your api is not returning the index, I was simply asking if you wanted to do something special with it. So you are currently using node to serve your static files? Yeah I would recommend a little *amazon web services* where you  can setup an nginx or maybe a dedicated server, but aws is really low-cost.